# DVWA sql injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I have a question about commenting out the sql query. 
The sql query has that form 
`$query  = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id';";`
So i try that `1' or 1=1;  #` and i get all the users and passwords as i expected but when i use `--` for a comment instead of `#` i get a syntax error. Why is that happening ? 
Can you explain how is the sql formed in each case ? 
Also i notice `1' or 1=1  #` works too. The # symbol doesnt comment out the ; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html):

> In MySQL, the --  (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on)

When adding only `--` to your input... there is no whitespace or control character following. Your synthesized query would look like that:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '1' or 1=1--';
```

As you can see, the double dash is followed *immediately* by a `;` which leads to a syntax error as it is not considered a comment.

Try putting in `--` (with a trailing whitespace) at the end

For the `;`: It is not necessary in a query issued to the server. This is *only* to separate different statements but with a single statement not required at all.

The mysql command line client does not send that character to the server but treats it as an "execution instruction".